# how to update customer and order details from magento to ERP using event observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I need to update the customers data from magento to ERP.

whenever customer going to check out the order,it ask for **Guest** or **Register and checkout**.
when we select the **Register and check out** option,it ask for billing information.after filling these details it ask for shipping details,for instance if we select billing address as shipping address,then ask for shipping method(for instance we select free shipping),then ask for payment method(for instance,if we select cash on deliver),after that order review.

how can i send these customer information and order details to our ERP,using event Observer?
(iam new to magento,if anyone have idea pls share here).

these files i created,Is there any mistakes these files,please correct here?

**Observer.php**[app/code/local/Wli/SalesOrderafter/Model]

```
<?php

class Wli_SalesOrderafter_Model_Observer {

    public function SalesOrderafter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $event = $observer->getEvent();


        $order = $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();

        echo "email:$order";


        exit();
    }

}
```

**config.xml** [app/code/local/Wli/SalesOrderafter/etc]

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wli_SalesOrderafter>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wli_SalesOrderafter>
  </modules>
  <global>
  <events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
      <observers>
        <Wli_SalesOrderafter_sales_order_place_after>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>Wli_SalesOrderafter_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>SalesOrderafter</method>
        </Wli_SalesOrderafter_sales_order_place_after>
     </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
  </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Wli_SalesOrderafter.xml**[app/etc/modules]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wli_SalesOrderafter>
      <active>true</active>
     <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Wli_SalesOrderafter>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following events:

```
sales_order_place_before
sales_order_place_after
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action
```

In your case, you would like to get info after successful order creation. In that case you should use `sales_order_place_after`.

Sending data to your **ERP** would completely depend upon ERP's system requirements. You will need to understand how they can receive data or in what format.

You can check all events here: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

**Update**

your observer function:

```
public function SalesOrderafter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{   $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
    $email = $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail(); 
    //echo "email:$order"; exit(); 

    Mage::log($email . " - order placed", null, 'custom_log.log');
}
```

This should create a file called `custom_log.log` in `/var/log` folder on order submit.

**Update 2**

Your event should be this

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_before>
      <observers>
        <unique_name>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>Wli_SalesOrderafter_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>SalesOrderafter</method>
        </unique_name>
     </observers>
    </sales_order_place_before>
  </events>
```

Comment: using  sales_order_place_after.Can i get customer data?

Comment: You can get everything that customer has entered.

Comment: when am using sales_order_place_after...it shows empty page

Comment: you can see the code here,which i was using http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80645/how-to-get-customer-information-using-event-observer

Comment: If customer is not register then calling getCustomerEmail() will not return anything. You have to call $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();   And what do you mean by empty page?

Comment: after click on the place order=>url link goes to=======> checkout/cart/

Comment: Any error? When it takes to cart page does it clears the cart or does it create the order?

Comment: no error.but it again ask for checkout

Comment: Can you place your `observer` code.

Comment: whenever i click on the place order option it automatically come to checkout/cart page...here option are looking like agin we have to checkout as we done previously

Comment: It could be anything, can you place your observer.php code in to qst and also have a look here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/customers-being-redirected-after-pressing-place-order

Comment: <?php

class Wli_SalesOrderafter_Model_Observer {

    public function SalesOrderafter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {   $event = $observer->getEvent();                                                                                   $order=$order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
        
        echo "email:$order";             exit();
        
        
}}

Comment: You cann't do echo there. See my update answer in a minute.

Comment: order is submitted but file (custom_log.log) was not created in /var/log folder

Comment: Check my update.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite broad so no ready-to-go answer but a list of what you need to know / check in order to build a module like this.

If you run into specific problems, feel free to post another question.

- How to build a custom module in Magento, check [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643) and [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/) but remember, you only need a model in your case.
- Check [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-events-in-magento-with-the-observer-pattern--cms-22120) about observers.
- The events: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/
- To check what data is in an event, go to the event in the code. It'll look somewhat like `Mage::dispatchEvent('[event]', array('order' => $order));` which means you can get the order in your observer via `$observer->getOrder();`
- And finally, read the documentation from the ERP on how to send the data to them.

But just to give you a little extra info, you're looking for the `sales_order_place_after` event.