# how to get customer information using event observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have already posted a question regarding this,
[how to update customer and order details from magento to ERP using event observer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80628/how-to-update-customer-and-order-details-from-magneto-to-erp-using-event-observe/80631#80631)

my files are as follows:

**Config.xml**   [app/code/local/Wli/Checkoutdemo/etc]

```
    <config>
  <modules>
    <Wli_Checkoutdemo>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Wli_Checkoutdemo>
  </modules>
  <global>
  <events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
      <observers>
        <Wli_Checkoutdemo_sales_order_place_after>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>Wli_Checkoutdemo_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>Checkoutdemo</method>
        </Wli_Checkoutdemo_sales_order_place_after>
     </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
  </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Wli_Checkoutdemo.xml**[app/etc/modules]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wli_Checkoutdemo>
      <active>true</active>
     <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Wli_Checkoutdemo>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**   [app/code/local/Wli/Checkoutdemo/Model]

```
<?php

class Wli_Checkoutdemo_Model_Observer {

    public function Checkoutdemo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customer = $event->getCustomer();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        print_r($order);
        exit();
    }

}
```

I need to get the details which are entered by the customer here.

after placing the order I didn't get anything?

what's wrong here?

what are the steps I have to follow here?
(I am new to Magento, if anyone has any idea pls share here)

Comment: What is actually the error/problem you are getting here?

Comment: always dump data to log files , you can use Mage::log('Your custom log here'); dont use print_r and exit

Answer (score 4):

You can get a lot of customer details directly from the order object

```
$order->getCustomerEmail();
$order->getCustomerFirstname();
```

etc... You can see a lot of them by looking at the class comments in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

But you can also get the customer object from the order too like so

```
$customer = $order->getCustomer();
```

Answer (score 1):

The event `sales_order_place_after` sends the order and only the order during the dispatch process.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_place_after', array('order'=>$this));
```

This means that your code `$customer = $event->getCustomer();` will not return anything. But you should be able to get the complete order information from `$order = $event->getOrder();`

This will give you a model of type `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` which will contain all the information about the order itself. From this model you should be able to get anything you need to know about the order.